# Suddenly, only Pen drive not recognized. All other USB's working?

Tags: usb

I've used pen drives many times on my system. I used a friend's pen drive and it worked once or twice. Then suddenly, whenever I inserted it, it gave three quick beeps and the pen drive was not detected. Restarted system etc and no use. Same thing happened on my friends system. But the pen drive works fine on a laptop that we have.
There's no virus in the pen drive. I checked it in Linux, doing `ls -lrth`.

All other USB devices are being recognized. Only the pen drive isn't. Why does this happen? Does some registry key get corrupted? Or is it that some windows driver has to be installed for pen drives?

Comment: What Windows version are we talking about?

Comment: Windows XP SP2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Having your Flash drive connected, go to Start menu and type "Device Manager" in search box.
2. Open the Device Manager and navigate to "Other devices" where you will most probably see a yellow exclamation mark next to the icon of a device called "Unknown".
3. Right-click on the device and select Uninstall.
4. Restart your PC (before Windows loads, disconnect your Flash)
5. After restart, connect your Flash

The device should now install (plug-n-play) and be available.